# How can I use each line like an argument in text output?

Tags: bash

I've got a file with text like a

111
222
333
444
555

I want that each line was an argument for text block:

Input=file.name
Hello world $Input
Output:
Hello world 111
Hello world 222
Hello world 333
Hello world 444
Hello world 555

How can I do that in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks like a homework problem, here are the best resources I know of to learn this: You can [read a file in a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), then use a simple [parameter substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) in a [string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).